# Why is an Accepting NFA in NL

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

I am reading the definition of NL complexity, but I'm having a hard time with a simple example.

Let's say I have an NFA Turing Machine $<M, w>$.

This is an accepting NFA Turing Machine, meaning that $M$ accepts an input string $w$.

Why is this NFA $\in$ NL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with.

We know that the problem of determining whether there is a path between two vertices in a directed graph runs in logarithmic space. We can consider A to be a directed graph, and check all final states to see if it is reachable from the start state. Thus A NFA must also be in NL.

Answer (score 3):

To prove that the acceptance language for NFA is done in logarithmic space ($\in NL$), we can go with an NL algorithm that non-deterministically guesses a path of length $n$ (number of states in NFA), state by state, and if at any point it reaches a final state, it accepts.

Since we are looking for a final (i.e., accepting) state, in every point of computation, we just need to know at which state we are. So we can encode current state into the work tape which is done in $O(log|<N>|)$ space, where $<N>$ is the description of NFA machine.